# Paginação no final da pagina

Tags: php, javascript, html, mysql

Tenho um sistema em que mostra 8 dados por pagina, meu problema e que a paginação quando só tem um dado na pagina ou 2 fica do lado dos dados, tipo: dados 1 - dados 2 - Pagina 1, eu queria que ficasse no final da pagina como acontece quando tem 8 dados... Segue o codigo:

```html
<?php 
    include_once("../../conn/conexao.php");//faz a conexao com o banco de dados
     
    //verifica a página atual caso seja informada na URL, senão atribui como 1ª página 
    $pagina = (isset($_GET['pagina']))? $_GET['pagina'] : 1; 
 
    //seleciona todos os itens da tabela 
    $cmd = "select * from tb_numeros"; 
    $produtos = mysqli_query($conexao, $cmd); 
 
    //conta o total de itens 
    $total = mysqli_num_rows($produtos); 
 
    //seta a quantidade de itens por página, neste caso, 2 itens 
    $registros = 8; 
 
    //calcula o número de páginas arredondando o resultado para cima 
    $numPaginas = ceil($total/$registros); 
 
    //variavel para calcular o início da visualização com base na página atual 
    $inicio = ($registros*$pagina)-$registros; 
 
    //seleciona os itens por página 
    $cmd = "select * from tb_numeros limit $inicio,$registros"; 
    $produtos = mysqli_query($conexao, $cmd); 
    $total = mysqli_num_rows($produtos); 
     
    //exibe os produtos selecionados 
       
                           
       echo "<div class='container'>
            <div class='row pricing text-center'>

            ";
            $cont=0;
                while ($produto = mysqli_fetch_array($produtos)){

                    echo"<div class='col-md-3'>
                    <div class='well'>";


             echo "<h3><b>".$produto['numero']."</b></h3>
                    <hr>
                    <p>Chip:&nbsp;".$produto['nchip']."</p>
                    <hr>
                    <p>IMEI:&nbsp;".$produto['imei']."</p>
                    <hr>

                    <div class='col-xs-6'>
                    <a href='deletarn.php?numero=".$produto['numero']."' class='btn btn-danger btn-block'><span class='glyphicon glyphicon-trash'></span></a></div>
                    <div class='col-xs-6'><a href='#info".$cont."' data-toggle='modal' class='btn btn-success btn-block'><span class='glyphicon glyphicon-plus'></span>&nbsp;Info</a></div>


<div class='modal fade' id='info".$cont."' tabindex='-1' role='dialog' aria-labelledby='myModalLabel' aria-hidden='true'>
    <div class='modal-dialog'>
        <div class='modal-content'>
          <div class='modal-header'>
                <button type='button' class='close' data-dismiss='modal'><span aria-hidden='true'>×</span><span class='sr-only'>Close</span></button>
                <h3 class='modal-title' id='lineModalLabel' align='center'>Dados do Telefone</h3>

            <div class='modal-body'>
                <div class='form-group'>
                    <div class='col-xs-12'><center>
                    <label for='exampleInputPassword1'>Funcionário</label></center>
                    <input type='text' name='funcionario' class='form-control' value=".$produto['funcionario']." style='text-align: center;' readonly='readonly' id='letras' required>
                    <br></div>
                </div>

                <div class='form-group'>
                    <div class='col-xs-4'><center>
                    <label for='exampleInputPassword1'>Número</label></center>
                    <input type='text' name='numero' class='form-control' id='exampleInputPassword1' value=".$produto['numero']." style='text-align: center;' readonly='readonly' >
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class='form-group'>
                    <div class='col-xs-2'><center>
                    <label for='exampleInputPassword1'>RCA</label></center>
                    <input type='text' name='rca' class='form-control' id='exampleInputPassword1' value=".$produto['rca']." style='text-align: center;' maxlength='4' readonly='readonly' onkeypress='return SomenteNumero(event)' required>
                    </div>
                </div>

               <div class='form-group'>
                    <div class='col-xs-6'><center>
                    <label for='exampleInputPassword1'>Região</label></center>
                    <input type='text' name='regiao' class='form-control' id='exampleInputPassword1' value=".$produto['regiao']." style='text-align: center;' readonly='readonly' required>
                    <br></div>
                </div>

                <div class='form-group'>
                    <div class='col-xs-6'><center>
                    <label for='exampleInputPassword1'>Número Chip</label></center>
                    <input type='text' name='nchip' class='form-control' id='exampleInputPassword1' value=".$produto['nchip']." style='text-align: center;' readonly='readonly' >
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class='form-group'>
                    <div class='col-xs-6'><center>
                    <label for='exampleInputPassword1'>IMEI</label></center>
                    <input type='text' name='imei' class='form-control' id='exampleInputPassword1' value=".$produto['imei']." style='text-align: center;' readonly='readonly' >
                    <br></div>
                </div>

                <div class='form-group'>
                    <div class='col-xs-12'><center>
                    <label for='exampleInputPassword1'>Cadastrado Por</label></center>
                    <input type='text' name='usuario' class='form-control' id='exampleInputPassword1' value=".$produto['usuario']." style='text-align: center;' readonly='readonly' >
                    <br></div>
                </div>


            </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
             </div>
             </div>
             ";


            $cont++;
                }

   echo "<div class='text-center'><ul class='pagination pagination-large'>";
    for($i = 1; $i < $numPaginas + 1; $i++) { 
     echo "              
  <li><a href='visualizarn.php?pagina=$i'>".$i."</a></li> "; 
    } 
 echo"</ul></div>
 </div>
  </div>
 ";
  
         
?>
```

Como fica:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Mais se eu adicionar todos os números fica do jeito que eu quero, que e exatamente assim:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Posta uma imagem de como está e como deveria ficar. Provavelmente seu problema é com CSS, se o Grid for com Float, vc vai precisar de um Clear-Fix. Mas com as imagens fica mais fácil de entender

Comment: @hugocsl coloquei a imagem na pergunta de uma olhada, eu uso bootstrap

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Parece que vc está usando Bootstrap pelas `tags` do grid. E onde vc chama sua paginação peço `PHP` *vc não usou as classes do grid na div*.

Tenta colocar a div da paginação tipo assim pra ver se da certo

```
echo "<div class='form-group'><div class='col-xs-12'><div class='text-center'><ul class='pagination pagination-large'>";
    for($i = 1; $i < $numPaginas + 1; $i++) { 
        echo "              
<li><a href='visualizarn.php?pagina=$i'>".$i."</a></li> "; 
    } 
echo"</ul></div></div></div>
```

Repare que eu coloquei duas tags por fora da ul  e estendi o grid para a largura tota 12.